# Unable to Reference 'Name' Column for SP Calculate Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I created an SP document library and moved 2700 .jpg files into it.

I am trying to create a Calculated column that looks at the 'Name' column in the library and extracts characters 1 - 4 the first new column and characters 6 -9 for second new column.

My issue is I CAN NOT see 'Name' as an option in the column list when creating the calculated column. I can see several autogenerated SP columns, including 'Title' (which was not auto-populated when the files were uploaded.

All files names in the Library are formatted as CQYear UniqueID CQTitle (2020 RR0000 Driver...)

I'd like to add columns for CQYr, UnqID, CQTitle
2020  RR0000 Driver

Comment: This is SharePoint default behavior, Name field is not available to use in calculated column formulas

Comment: Then how do I NOW, after already uploading the files, reference the names of each image to created a new column in the library based on extract pieces of the file name through a calculation?

Answer (score 0):

For referring the name field value in the library to get the substring of it, it may be better to use workflow for SharePoint on-premise or Power Automate for SharePoint Online.

Workflow reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-designer-2013-extract-substring-of-string-from-index-with-length-action

Power Automate:https://www.timlinenterprises.com/microsoft-flow-substring/